# Getting ErrImagePull when trying to use Local Docker Registry with Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

First I create a local Docker registry...

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
```

Then I push

```
docker push localhost:5000/jrg/hello-k8s
```

I confirm it is there by

```
$ docker pull localhost:5000/jrg/hello-k8s
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from jrg/hello-k8s
Digest: sha256:c475cb7167208e8f018e54ad81d4b7bbbb9c14875bc1624bcce730edf9afede0
Status: Image is up to date for localhost:5000/jrg/hello-k8s:latest
```

Then I start Minikube

```
minikube start --insecure-registry=localhost:5000
```

But when I run

```
kubectl create deployment hello-k8s --image=localhost:5000/jrg/hello-k8s
```

I get

```
NAME                          READY   STATUS         RESTARTS   AGE
hello-k8s-75846c4bfc-b7zp7    0/1     ErrImagePull   0          4s
```

What am I missing?

**Update**

I also tried (assuming 5.5.5.5 is the IP address for my wireless adapter (confirmed by accessing in the browser).

Then I start Minikube

```
minikube start --insecure-registry=5.5.5.5:5000
```

But when I run

```
kubectl create deployment hello-k8s --image=5.5.5.5:5000/jrg/hello-k8s
```

But I still get the same issue, also after a while it appears to become `ImagePullBackOff`

FYI Project (https://github.com/jrgleason/hello-kubernetes/tree/ADD_CASSANDRA)

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is `localhost` will reference the kubernetes host itself, and not your registry.

You need to make it so that the registry is accessible from inside minikube. Try using the ip address of your computer instead of `localhost`.

There is a proxy addon for minikube that will allow you to access `localhost` from within minikube. I would suggest setting this up as the simplest solution https://github.com/Faithlife/minikube-registry-proxy

If this doesn't work there is a guide here to setup minikube with a local registry https://blog.hasura.io/sharing-a-local-registry-for-minikube-37c7240d0615/

Comment: Ok so I tried using my actual IP (ifconfig) to both the registry param and the deployment creation but getting the same thing. Would I be missing something?

Comment: Did you also use your ip to tag and push up the image, and for the `--insecure-registry`?

Comment: Yeah I will update the question one sec... Still not working though

Comment: Added some more detail, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I've updated my answer with a proxy that is designed to get round the localhost issue. Looks fairly easy to setup.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using minikube you must start the docker registry on the minikube machine.
You can either use the minikube registry addon, or use docker yourself. Make sure to use the docker daemon from the minikube host:

```
eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

You must push the image to the right registry then, f.e. by using the remote docker daemon for building and pushing to 'localhost' (which is the minikube VM in that case)

Comment: I think I have to read this a little deeper and I will confirm but I am pretty sure it was built with the eval properly. Are you suggesting the terminal that also starts another process must also have that?

Comment: Yes, the environment is only set for the currently active terminal window where the eval is executed.

Comment: Any chance you have documentation that explains this in a bit more detail? I still can't get it to work and I am not sure which terminal command is having the issue and I think I have tested them all.

Comment: The setup with minikube having a separate VM, providing a docker environment on its own can be really confusing, when starting with kubernetes. I recommend to just use an external registry until you are more familiar with the concepts. If you want to keep on using minikube: Do the eval-docker-env in the SAME terminal window where you afterwards to the docker build/push and it will use the right environment.